# DxaPropertyMarkup for managing lists of items in XPM

Tags: dxa, experience-manager, dxa2.2

I have a list of Embedded Schema objects that I want to be able to reorder, add, and remove in the list in XPM.

I cannot find any examples of the correct `DxaPropertyMarkup` to be able to do this.

```
@if (item.calltoaction.Count > 0)
{
    <ul class="unstyled">
        @foreach (EmbeddedCallToAction calltoaction in item.calltoaction)
        {

            <li @Html.DxaPropertyMarkup(() => item.calltoaction)>
                <a class="@htmlClasses" href="@link" target="@target" title="@title" @Html.DxaPropertyMarkup(() => calltoaction.externallink)>
                    <span @Html.DxaPropertyMarkup(() => calltoaction.label)>@label</span>

                </a>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the add, remove, reorder functionality for multivalue properties, you must use the `DxaPropertyMarkup` method with an index. For multivalue "embedded properties", this should wrap all individual property markups.

```
@Html.DxaPropertyMarkup(() => Model.MultiValueProperty, index)
```

In your example, the following line needs to be modified:

```
<li @Html.DxaPropertyMarkup(() => item.calltoaction)>
```

As a reference, there is an example in the Core module [here](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-modules/blob/master/webapp-net/Core/Areas/Core/Views/Entity/Accordion.cshtml) (line 15).